# Excel: Use Cell in Formula Based On Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have the following Excel workbook sheets.

SHEET 1 contains data on criminal sentences handed down for specific individuals:

```
| Name | DateOfBirth | DateOfSentence | SentenceYears |
|------|-------------|----------------|---------------|
| A    | 01/01/1960  | 04/06/2007     | 30            |
| B    | 21/03/1964  | 12/10/2009     | 25            |
```

SHEET 2 contains the average life expectancies for people born in specific years:

```
| 1960 | 1961 | 1962        | 1963           | 1964          |
| 65   | 65   | 66          | 67             | 67            |
```

I want to create a formula to determine if the sentence imposed (from SHEET 1, column SentenceYears) is like to imprison the person beyond their anticipated life expectancy based on the average figure for someone born in the same year in SHEET 2. If true, return "LIKELY DEAD", if false, return "LIKELY NOT DEAD".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! I have no experience with pointing Excel to specific cells based on date matching.

Comment: Sheet2 allows to calculate (year of birth - average year of death). Then compare it with birth date and "predict".

Comment: Thanks @Akina, but how to tell Excel what the correct column is to look at to find the life expectancy based on the year of the individual's birth?

Comment: Look into [`HLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HLOOKUP-function-A3034EEC-B719-4BA3-BB65-E1AD662ED95F). You may also want to consider transposing the data and using [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Follow these steps to fix the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Step 1: Find `Age On Sentence Year` & `Age On Sentence Completed`.
- Formula in Cell `F91` in `Sheet 1`:

  `=DATEDIF(B91,C91,"Y")`
- Formula in Cell `G91` in `Sheet 1`:

  `=F91+D91`
- Formula in cell `H91` in `Sheet 1`:

`=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!A$97:E$97,MATCH(YEAR(B91),Sheet2!A$96:E$96,0))<G91,"Dead","NotDead")`

**N.B.**

- `=INDEX(A$97:E$97,MATCH(YEAR(B91),A$96:E$96,0))` returns `65` for Prisoner `A` & `67` for `B`, and both are less than `Age On Sentence Completed`.
- Therefore both are likely dead when complete the sentence.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Craig ,, keep asking ☺